# KafkaMessageListenerContainer Receiving 0 Records

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a simple Kafka application that is supposed to consume a json file. The Kafka server is running locally on port 9092. Zookeeper is running as well.  I have a data.json file with user data.  I have a User.json file containing the user schema with object types and the javatype pointing to a User.java class the matches the User.json schema.

**KafkaConfig:**

```
import com.microservices.kafka.model.User;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.EnableKafka;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.*;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.StringJsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    private static final String BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS = "localhost:9092";

    public static ProducerFactory<String, User> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config);
    }

    public static ConsumerFactory<String, User> consumerFactory(String groupId) {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(User.class));
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, User> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, User> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory("employeeGroup"));
        factory.setMessageConverter(new StringJsonMessageConverter());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

**User:**

```
package com.microservices.kafka.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class User {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private String email;

    private String status;



}
```

**KafkaApplication**

```
package com.microservices.kafka;

import com.microservices.kafka.config.KafkaConfig;
import com.microservices.kafka.model.User;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.JsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.RecordMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.converter.StringJsonMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})

public class KafkaApplication {

    private static final String TOPIC_NAME = "employeeTopic";
    private static final String GROUP_ID = "employeeGroup";

    private static final ConsumerRecord<String, User> record = null;

    private static final Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaApplication.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(KafkaApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RecordMessageConverter converter() {
        return new StringJsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonMessageConverter jsonConverter() {
        return new JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public JsonDeserializer<User> deserializer() {
        return new JsonDeserializer<>(User.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public String loadData() throws IOException {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/data/data.json");
        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(resource.getURI()));
        logger.info("Loading data from file " + resource.getFilename());
        return new String(bytes);
    }

}
```

**KafkaListeners:**

```
import com.microservices.kafka.model.User;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 * The @Autowired annotation is used to inject an instance of ObjectMapper into the class.
 * This is an instance of Jackson's ObjectMapper class, which is used to deserialize JSON data into Java objects.
 *
 * The @KafkaListener annotation is used to define a Kafka listener that will listen for messages
 * on the employeeTopic topic. The groupId parameter specifies the ID of the consumer group that this
 * listener is part of. The containerFactory parameter specifies the name of the Kafka listener container factory to use.
 *
 * The listen() method is the actual message listener method that will be called when a message is
 * received. It takes a ConsumerRecord<String, String> parameter that contains the Kafka message.
 * In this case, we assume that the message contains a JSON string representing a User object.
 *
 * The readValue() method of the ObjectMapper class is used to deserialize the JSON string into a User object.
 * We assume that the JSON string is stored in the value() property of the ConsumerRecord.
 *
 * Finally, we print out the received User object to the console.
 */
@Component
public class KafkaListeners {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @KafkaListener(
            topics = "employeeTopic",
            groupId = "group_id",
            containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory"
    )
    public void listen(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) throws IOException {
        String fileContent = record.value();
        User user = objectMapper.readValue(fileContent, User.class);
        System.out.println("Received user: " + user);
    }
}
```

**User.json:**

```
  "type": "object",
  "javaType": "com.microservices.kafka.model.User",
  "properties": {
    "id": {
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "firstName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "lastName": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "status": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

The `data.json` file contains mock data corresponding to the User.json schema.  As I said, it runs but it doesn't return anything. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: How does the data appear in the `employeeTopic`? You showed only a `@KafkaListener` and some `loadData` string bean. But there is no code which would use a `KafkaTemplate` for publishing data into the topic.

Comment: @Artem Bilan: What am I missing exactly?  I'm learning Kafka.

Comment: Your configuration is incorrect; see my answer.

Comment: Well, I just explained you: to make the data in the topic you need to publish it somehow: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#sending-messages

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET=earliest` - by default, it is `latest` which means consume only new records published after the consumer consumes.

Also, since you are configuring a `JsonDeserializer` you should just consume the object, not a `String` and do the deserialization yourself.